# Delphi android/iphone cache for firemonkey controls (using openGL Texture)

Tags: android, iphone, delphi, opengl-es, firemonkey

I want to improuve the rendering of Firemonkey visual components. for this the idea is to "cache" the paint in some TTexture or in Tbitmap (i don't know with is the best).

it's work good, for exemple i can reduce from 3ms to 0.1 ms the draw of a Trectangle with round corners using Ttexture Cache. The main problem now is that to create this Ttexture cache it's cost me around 30 ms !

this is the code i use, if someone have any idea how i can do to speed it :

```
function TCacheRectangle.MakeBufBitmap: TTexture;
var TmpBitmap: Tbitmap;
    M: TBitmapData;
    SaveTempCanvas: TCanvas;
    SceneScale: Single;
begin

  if Scene <> nil then SceneScale := Scene.GetSceneScale
  else SceneScale := 1;

  TmpBitmap := Tbitmap.Create(round(Width * SceneScale), round(height * SceneScale));
  try
    TmpBitmap.BitmapScale := SceneScale;
    TmpBitmap.Clear(0);
    if TmpBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
    try
      SaveTempCanvas := TempCanvas;
      try
        TempCanvas := TmpBitmap.Canvas;
        inherited paint;
      finally
        TempCanvas := SaveTempCanvas;
      end;
    finally
      TmpBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
    end;
    //-----
    fBufBitmap := TTexture.Create;
    fBufBitmap.Assign(TmpBitmap);
    if (TCanvasStyle.NeedGPUSurface in TmpBitmap.CanvasClass.GetCanvasStyle) then begin
      if TmpBitmap.Map(TMapAccess.Read, M) then begin
        try
          fBufBitmap.UpdateTexture(M.Data, M.Pitch);
        finally
          TmpBitmap.Unmap(M);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    //-----
  finally
    TmpBitmap.Free;
  end;

end;
```

it is mostly slow on this instruction: TmpBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;

after i don't know also what it's the best to use: TTexture or Tbitmap. i think Ttexture are stored in GPU memory and Tbitmap in local memory but i don't really understand the advantage/disadvantage of each (what if no more gpu memory, how to check it, how to compress a Ttexture using png for exemple, etc)